# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el "ctrl + click" para escribir en varias lineas al mismo tiempo en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode, sublimetext3

Esta función viene por defecto en SublimeText3, pero en VScode no se como configurarla o implementarla.

Comment: Prueba con `ctrl + alt + flecha subir/bajar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma predeterminada está configurado con `alt+click` pero lo puedes cambiar en el menu `selection - Use Ctrl+Click for Multi-Cursor` [ver más](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias me funcionó!

Answer (score 0):

Para marcar varias líneas de código con el cursor simultáneamente en VS Code:

- Pulsando la rueda del ratón y arrastrando hacía arriba o abajo.
- Alt + Click
- Si no tienes ratón - ctrl + alt + flecha arriba/abajo como había mencionado anteriormente **Sergio Avramescu**

Comment: No es lo que esta preguntando...

Comment: esta preguntando como configurarlo ;)

Comment: " pero en VScode no se como configurarla o implementarla." igual, te lo marcaba, porque sobre todo es una pregunta del 2020 con una respuesta aceptada...

Comment: El comentario complementa la pregunta... pero en ningún caso dice "quero configurar" sino ¿configurarla o implementarla? ¿ cómo sería posible hacer el ctrl + click en VS Code como en SublimeText3 - donde la función viene por defecto. En VS Code por defecto, según sepa yo, hay 3 maneras de multi-selección sin configurar nada. Es una pregunta antigua con una respuesta aceptada antigua pero yo no he venido a configurar nada sino agregar algo que faltaba, no crees?